# Flutter android Sealed classes are not supported as program classes error

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting below error when building Flutter app for android

ERROR:/Users/otabekochilov/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/99d4ac1fb93dcdf71f5d6e6abf284220/transformed/jetified-lottie-compose-6.2.0-runtime.jar: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.YI0: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDevDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform lottie-compose-6.2.0.aar (com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:6.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/otabekochilov/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/99d4ac1fb93dcdf71f5d6e6abf284220/transformed/jetified-lottie-compose-6.2.0-runtime.jar.
> > Error while dexing.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was flutter_intercom related.

See: https://github.com/v3rm0n/intercom_flutter/issues/394 and update package to 8.0.9